# Error trying to import dump form mysql 5.7 into 8.0.23

Tags: mysql, migrate

I am trying to import a dump that I created with `mysqldump` from `mysql:5.7`, into one instance of `mysql:8.0.23`

trying to import the .sql dump, gives me error

```
dest_host=myrds.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
dest_username=theuser
dest_password=thepasword
dest_database=cats
filename="2021-05-07_15_21_13.sql"
mysql -h ${dest_host} -u ${dest_username} -p${dest_password} ${dest_database} < "$filename"

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

I am using the master user in the dest_* variables!
The user created to manage the AWS RDS MySQL instance that is supposed to have all privileges

(of course that is the user for version 8.0.23. I dumped fine the .sql from version 5.7 with the master user of v5.7 db)

I really need help here how to import the dump ?

And by the way error says line 18 and I have no idea what that line 18 is!!!

If it refers to the dump file initial lines until 18 are:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.34, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: sosecretolddb.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com    Database: cats
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.26-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;

--
-- GTID state at the beginning of the backup 
--

SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED='';

--
-- Table structure for table `activity_types`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `activity_types`;
# and so on 1.3gb of data
```

Comment: And what is at `line 18:`

Comment: What is unclear about " Access denied; you need (at least one of)......" ? And please include the output of `mysql -h ${dest_host} -u ${dest_username} -p${dest_password} ${dest_database} -e "SHOW GRANTS\G"`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have all access rights in an RDS mysql instance as it is a managed service. You need to check what causes the access denied issue and consider if you can remove or change that operation. We cannot really help as you have not shared what causes the error message.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I pasted here line 18 is the mysqldump command, as part of a bash script where this command was located in line 18 `mysql -h ${dest_host} -u ${dest_username} -p${dest_password} ${dest_database} < "$filename"
`

Comment: @Shadow I do not know how to do that, because the user I am using is `master` one that I se up via AWS RDS MySQL interface, so no user has more privileges then this one. I used this user to create other users, databases etc too

Comment: "line 18" refers to the sql dump, not the import script (if line 18 there is the mysql command, that's just a coincidence). So please add the code from the dump (it's most likely a `create` or `set` statement).

Comment: Sorry my mistake have been working 20 hour non stop on this ! line 18 is not the mysqldump, is just the damn import. The dump is successed and I have the dump file stored in the .sql with all sql statements. Just cannot import due to error above in mysql 8.0.23

Comment: You misunderstood again. After having slept, please open the file that $filename refers to (the one with all the sql statements), go to line 18, copy that line to your question.

Comment: Hi @Solarflare. This time I repeated the process without any bash script. Runned directly the mysql import command in terminal (after defining the cred vars), I still got error line 18... As easy as this: `root@57f9b4a2c1b1:/# mysql -h ${dest_host} -u ${dest_username} -p${dest_password} ${dest_database} < "$filename"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
`

Comment: So maybe line 18 is referring the the dump file ? Or internal mysql command error

Comment: Line 18 of $filename, the data.sql dump is `SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;`

Comment: I updated question with also providing part of the dump file that I am trying to import

Comment: @KristiJorgji Is https://help.poralix.com/articles/mysql-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privilege-for-this-operation an option for you?

Comment: I updated the source database to same engine 8.0.23, then tried import the dump again to another 8.0.23 mysql and still same error `Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the solution.

If I add this parameter to mysqldump, the import later will work fine:
`--set-gtid-purged=OFF \`

So my mysql dump now looks like below for the export:

```
mysqldump -h ${source_host} -u ${source_username} -p${source_password} \
  --lock-tables=false \
  --set-gtid-purged=OFF \
  --triggers \
  --routines \
  --events \
  --databases db1 db2 > "$filename";
```

Also what @Progman posted would work for `existing dumps`:
https://help.poralix.com/articles/mysql-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privilege-for-this-operation

Just commenting out those lines

Answer (score -1):

In Windows the simplest way is to make an server export and then import it in new server by using "MYSQL Workbanch".

That works seamlessly for me...

Answer (score -3):

The problem is with your user, check that it has admin priviledges so you can import to the database, you are doing the rest ok.

Comment: I have master user with all privilages, the user created after the AWS RDS MySQL instance. I can drop db create do all actions with this user, have no way to create user with more privileges then this